# Save virtualbox vm state before logout

Tags: virtualbox, scripts, logout

I'm using oneiric with unity. I want to find a solution to automatically save the state of my virtualbox virtual machine before I logout or shutdown because I always forget to do it manually. I know I can use `Vboxmanage controlvm [vmname] savestate` to save state in terminal. But how do I make ubuntu execute this command before logging out?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the Vboxmanage command to your ~/.bash_logout file and it will execute upon the logoff event.

Comment: Will this run automatically when logging out of an X session?  I think, at least, that X will be closed, taking VirtualBox with it, before ~/.bash_logout would be executed.  The best answer is for them to implement https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/1888 so VBox will do it automatically.  In the meantime, perhaps something like ~/.kde/shutdown, or whatever your DE provides, would help by running when you log out of your X session.